# python `os.system("xdg-open test.pdf")` doesn't open file

Tags: python, shell, os.system

I'm trying to run the `xdg-open test.pdf` command from within a python script, but nothing happens when I execute `os.system("xdg-open test.pdf")` even though it outputs code 0, and even though after executing `os.system("ls")` it does show the file `test.pdf`. I've also tried `subprocess.run("xdg-open test.pdf", shell=True)` and `subprocess.call(["xdg-open", "test.pdf"])`. On the other hand, if I run `xdg-open test.pdf` from the terminal (I'm on Ubuntu), it does open the pdf. What explains this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe this works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210112/python-xdg-open

Comment: did you try `/usr/bin/xdg-open /full/path/to/test.pdf` ? System may run it in different folder then you expect - or python code may run in different folder then you expect (check `os.getcwd()` and `os.system("pwd")` to see `Current Working Directory`) . BTW: you should get the same result with `import webbrowser` and `webbrowser.open("test.pdf")` because this module uses `xdg-open` to open url with default web browser.